# Bigquery - Filtering on Repeated Fields Using SemiJoins

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to select records from one table based on whether an item in a repeated field is located in a column in another table.  I've been able to do this when explicitly listing the items I am testing for in my code, but not when selecting from another table.  Let me demonstrate using the trigrams dataset:

Let's say that I wanted to select all records that had an appearance during certain years.  But I don't just want just the data from those years - I want all the data associated with those records.  If I just wanted the data for a few years I could do something like this (and this works):

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count,
    SOME(cell.value in ('1800', '1801')) WITHIN RECORD AS valid
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
HAVING valid
```

However, instead of coding '1800' and '1801' into my query, I have a table `years` that contains a set of years I am interested in.  I would like this to work:

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count,
    SOME(cell.value in (SELECT year_as_str FROM [mydataset.years])) WITHIN RECORD AS valid
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
HAVING valid
```

This doesn't work because bigquery requires that semi-joins be part of a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause.

So I try to rearrange (back to the first query):

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
HAVING SOME(cell.value in ('1801', '1802')) WITHIN RECORD
```

This results in an error `Encountered " "WITHIN" "WITHIN "" ... Was expecting <EOF>`

So now without the `WITHIN RECORD`:

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
HAVING SOME(cell.value in ('1801', '1802'))
```

This results in an error `SELECT clause has mix of aggregations '...' and fields '...' without GROUP BY clause`

But I'm not aggregating!  So now I move the filter into a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
WHERE SOME(cell.value in ('1801', '1802'))
```

And this tells me that `Invalid function name: SOME`.  What?!

Is there a way to get the behavior I am looking for with BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solves your example and I hope you will be able to extend it to your real use case (if you will like solution)

```
SELECT 
    ngram, cell.value, cell.volume_count, 
    cell.volume_fraction, cell.page_count, cell.match_count
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] AS trigrams
JOIN (
  SELECT ngram AS qualified
  FROM (
    FLATTEN((SELECT ngram, cell.value AS value
      FROM (FLATTEN([publicdata:samples.trigrams], cell.value))), value)
  ) AS t
  JOIN [mydataset.years] AS y
  ON y.year_as_str = t.value
  GROUP BY 1
) AS valid
ON valid.qualified = trigrams.ngram
```

Please pay attention to the fact that in `[publicdata:samples.trigrams]` the field `cell.value` is `REPEATED STRING` - that is why you see "extra" FLATTEN things

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OMIT RECORD IF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#omit) clause for this.  This may require double negation, since you need to omit records that meet some condition. The following query should work:

```
SELECT ngram, first, second, third, fourth, fifth, cell.value, cell.volume_count
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]
OMIT RECORD IF EVERY(cell.value NOT IN ('1801', '1802'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because if I replace `('1801', '1802')` with a subselect query, the overall query fails.  Mikhail's solution with a filter+self join works

Comment: Good point, sorry!  I missed that part of your question originally.